# Squid user external AUTH plus white list

Tags: squid

Not sure if I'm search on right terminology, haven't found a solution to this combination problem.

I have an external authentication that is working (tp. But once authenticated I want to restrict to a small white list (in configuration www.cnn.com as example).

I'm sure its an ordering/prioritisation type problem, but cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Following squid.conf works for external auth, but lets everything through (of course). Cannot seem to get whitelist to "connect/relate" to foo e.g. the authenticated item

```
# acl whitelist dstdomain .cnn.com
# http_access allow whitelist
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid Enter your ID into Username & Password

auth_param basic program /usr/local/bin/tp_squidauth.bash

# this works but it allows anything through once authorised
# what we want is to only restrict to the whitelist
acl foo proxy_auth REQUIRED

# how do i connect whitelist & foo together?
http_access allow foo

acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_reply_access allow all
icp_access allow all
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
```

hope this is obvious to somone!?

many thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0):

first, your `whitelist` command is commented out.

the main issue you are facing, happens because the elements of http_access should be 'AND' together for demanding both authentication AND 'whitelisting'.

so when you write two different lines for `http_access`, e.g.:

```
http_access allow foo
http_access allow whitelist
```

they are interpreted as "OR" and therefore either one will "hit".

if you want to force the proxy to only allow `foo` users to use `whitelist` acl, they have to be on the same line.
so in your case:

`http_access allow foo whitelist`

and that means - (only) allow `foo` AND `whitelist`.

followed by a `http_access deny all` this should block all other traffic as well.

```
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid Enter your ID into Username & Password
auth_param basic program /usr/local/bin/tp_squidauth.bash

acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
acl whitelist dstdomain .cnn.com
acl foo proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access allow localhost
http_access allow foo whitelist
http_access deny all

# not sure what these do, but if you need them, make sure this is the correct placement (order) for them.
http_reply_access allow all
icp_access allow all
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create a file with the desired whitelist pages:

/etc/squid/allowed.txt:

> Contents:

.google.com

.yahoo.com

.dropbox.com

Then you create the ACL

> acl allowed_pages dstdomain "/etc/squid/allowed.txt"

Then you allow the http access and deny the rest

> http_access allow allowed_pages
>
> http_access deny all

Comment: Nice copy-paste, but the whitelist the user is asking for is IP whitelist.